# Faster than light communication via entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

Let's say site S and site S' have a very large number N of pairs of entangled particles:

$(p_1 p_1') (p_2 p_2') \ldots (p_N p_N')$.

so particles $p_1 p_2 \ldots p_N$ are located at site S
and particles $p_1' p_2' \ldots p_N'$ are located at site S'.

to communicate the number 75 from site S to site S', at site S, do:

step 1)
measure spin UP/DOWN on particles $p_1 p_2 \ldots p_N$.
sustain measurement on all the particles whose spin is UP.
release measurement on all the particles whose spin is DOWN.
the set of "sustained-measurement-observed-spin-UP" particles will be $\sim N/2$.

step 2)
on the configuration obtained in step 1.
repeat method from step 1 on the remaining $\sim N/2$ particles that were released in step 1.
hereafter the total set of "sustained-measurement-observed-spin-UP" particles will be $\sim N/2 + \sim (N/2)/2 = ~3/4N$.
thus step 1 + 2 has caused ~75% of the particles at site S to be spin UP.

subsequently and as long as ~75% of the particles at site S are "sustained-measurement-observed-spin-UP", measurement at site S' on particles $p_1' p_2' \ldots p_N'$ will mirror the spins of $p_1 p_2 \ldots p_N$.
thus at site S', ~75% of the particles will be observed to be spin DOWN.

to transmit a higher number than 75 from S to S': add another step 3 and so on.

it would thus seem that site S and S' can communicate any suitably encoded message between them via sets of entangled sets of particles

$\lbrace p_1 p_2 \ldots \rbrace \lbrace q_1 q_2 \ldots \rbrace \lbrace r_1 r_2 \ldots \rbrace \ldots \longleftrightarrow \lbrace p_1' p_2' \ldots \rbrace \lbrace q_1' q_2' \ldots \rbrace \lbrace r_1' r_2' \ldots \rbrace \ldots$

the speed of transmission itself is instantaneous across any distance and is only limited practically by the speed with which measurements can be done.

since this would violate relativity theory, what is wrong with the above reasoning?

Comment: what does "sustain" and "release" means?

Comment: "sustain": the measurement is maintained = the particle is kept in its observed state, wave function is collapsed. release: the particle is not being measured, its  state is undetermined, according to the wave function, wave function is not collapsed.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean, but step 1 collapses all wavefunctions and destroys all entanglement. You cannot chose whether to measure it or not depending on the outcome of the measure!

Comment: Also, you want to encode information as "number of steps", but it seems that the two observers must agree on the number of steps in advance, so there is no communication (even neglecting the fact that the steps themselves do not work).

Comment: thanks @fqq. so "release measurement on all the particles whose spin is DOWN." --- this action will destroy the entanglement of said particles? if so, this is an easy to understand reason and answers a very basic property of entanglement which i was unaware of:-) thanks

Comment: @fqq, regarding the number of steps: no agreement is needed since N is very large. a randomly occurring number will always be very close to N/2. occcurrences of 3/4N, 7/8N etc will always be detectable as "chosen numbers".

Answer (score 3):

The [No Communication Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) says that it is not possible.